# PostgreSQL hierarchical nested set huge database

Tags: postgresql, indexing, nested-sets

I have a database that must store thousands of scenarios (each scenario with a single unix_timestamp value). Each scenario has 1,800,000 registers organized in a Nested Set structure.
The general table structure is given by:

```
table_skeleton:
 - unix_timestamp integer
 - lft integer
 - rgt integer
 - value
```

Usually, my SELECTs are will perform taking all nested values within an specific scenario, it means for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_skeleton WHERE unix_timestamp = 123 AND lft >= 10 AND rgt <= 53
```

So I hierarchically divided my table into master / children within groups of dates, for example:

```
table_skeleton_201303 inherits table_skeleton:
 - unix_timestamp integer
 - lft integer
 - ...
```

and

```
table_skeleton_201304 inherits table_skeleton:
 - unix_timestamp integer
 - lft integer
 - ...
```

And also created index for each children according to the usual search I am expecting, it is for example:

```
Create Index idx_201303 
on table_skeleton_201303 
using btree(unix_timestamp, lft, rgt)
```

It improved the retrieval, but it still takes about 1 minute for each select.
I imagined that this was because the index was too big to be loaded into memory always so I tried to create partial index for each timestamp, for example:

```
Create Index idx_201303_1362981600 
on table_skeleton_201303 
using btree(lft, rgt) 
WHERE unix_timestamp = 1362981600
```

And in fact the second type of index created is much, much, much smaller than the general one. However, when I run an EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the SELECT I've previously shown here, the query solver ignores my new partial index and keeps using the giant old one.

Is there a reason for that?
Is there any new approach to optimize such type of huge nested set hierarchical database?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`. Formatted text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or upload the plan to http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Where is there a true hierarchy? Seems to me that all you have done is partitioned the data by time blocks. The inheritence referred to is about the ddl, not the data.

Answer (score 3):

When you filter on a table by field_a > x and field_b > y, then an index for `field_a, field_b` will (actually just *may*, depending on the distribution and the percentage of rows with field_a > x, as per the statistics collected) only be used for "field_a > x", and field_b > y will be a sequential search.

In the case above, having two indexes, one for each field, could be used and each of the results joined, the internal equivalent of:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
JOIN (
  SELECT id table field_a > x) ta ON (ta.id = t.id)
JOIN (
  SELECT id table field_b > y) tb ON (tb.id = t.id);
```

There is a change you could benefit from a GIST index, and treating your lft and rgt fields as points:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table USING GIST (unix_timestamp, point(lft, rgt));

SELECT * table
WHERE unix_timestamp = 123 AND
      point(lft,rgt) <@ box(point(10,'-inf'), point('inf',53));
```